# I want to open a new Tab in React application on button click?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, window.open

I want to open a table tab in a new window to interact with the component separately. What's the best recommended method to do this functionality in React.js?

Answer (score 1):

try this pls . `<a href="URL_LINK" target="_blank"/>`.

such as :

```
<a href="http://localhost:3001/users" target="_blank"/> 
<a href="http://localhost:3001/personels" target="_blank"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try `target="_blank"` for opening new tab if you are using `<a href="SOME_URL" target="_blank"/>`
2. or you can use onClick event as shown `onClick={()=> window.open("someLink", "_blank")}` if you just need to put on button .